# Android json parsing

Tags: android, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день! Пытаюсь парсить http://rutube.ru/api/video/editors/?page=1&format=json.
Никаких ошибок нет, но данные не грузятся!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_VIDEO);
        try {               
            results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = results.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject video = c.getJSONObject(VIDEO_OBJECT);
            String id = video.getString(VIDEO_ID);
            String title = video.getString(VIDEO_TITLE);
            String created_ts = video.getString(VIDEO_CREATED_TS);
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(VIDEO_ID, id);
            map.put(VIDEO_TITLE, title);
            map.put(VIDEO_CREATED_TS, created_ts);
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList, 
                R.layout.list_video_item, 
                new String[] { VIDEO_TITLE, VIDEO_CREATED_TS }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.created_ts });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Логгируйте и смотрите что там у вас происходит - мы же не экстрасенсы и не видим что там у вас

Comment: а вы через браузер пробовали эту ссылку открывать? Она JSON не отдает.... 404

Answer (score 1):

Вы не правильно составили URL  
Правильный URL:  
`http://rutube.ru/api/video/editors/?format=json&page=1`  
Ваш URL:  
`http://rutube.ru/api/video/editors/?page=1&format=json`

Это конечно абсурд, но оказывается порядок параметров имеет значение...

Comment: В логах пишет org.json.JSONEXCEPTION: No value for results

Comment: Проблему решил самостоятельно, тему можно закрыть!