# Парсить JSON с сайта

Tags: android, json, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте! Как сделать чтобы при включение android программы она парсила JSON например от сюда;

> site.ru/bd.json

и выводила его в ListView?

Зарание спасибо!

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/258496/android-json-parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `AsyncTask` получаете json строку, потом парсите с помощью классов из пакета **org.json** (или либой какой-нить) и добавляет в список.
Потом создаёте свой адаптер, передаёте туда список. Адаптер вешаете на свой ListView.

Пример парсинга:

```
String req; // здесь у нас ответ от сервера
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(req); // преобразуем в json объект
```

Например ответ от сервера у нас: {"result":"OK"}

Тогда можете пропарсить его и полуить result:

```
String res = jObj.getString("result");
```

ну и т.д.

Comment: А не можете дать пример кода?

Comment: Чего именно? Тут много чего написать можно. И по ключевым словам, которые я привел, уже можно гуглить дальше. 
Брать готовое решение - не путь истинного программиста.

Comment: Мне бы хотя бы код самого парсинга

Comment: @FreemanDNS обновил ответ